# How can I use bound version of core Maven plugin, but override its configuration?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I want to override configuration of a **core** Maven plugin in my POM.

Example:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <!-- my configuration here -->
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Maven gives a warning that a version for the plugin is missing. I would like to use the version from [default binding](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/default-bindings.html), but don't seem to find a way to do it.

1. Are there better ways to override a core plugin's configuration without (potentially) changing its version?
2. Should I just ignore the warning?

Thanks

**Clarification**: I'm familiar with the best practices. However, in my opinion **core** plugins are different in that they already have explicitly declared versions. Maven is also free to add new core plugins, in which case a default version will be used despite any attempts to pin the versions. Moreover, Maven doesn't warn when the default version of a core plugin is being used — as long as you don't try to override its configuration that is.

Answer (score 1):

It's a best practice to set all plugin versions in the pluginManagement section of the parent POM.

Reason: Some plugins change their behaviour slightly in some versions. Pinning the plugin versions is a key to get stable builds with Maven.

Please note that I've written a parent POM, which provides a lot of common configuration. The code is Open Source, you can use it as the parent of your parent POM (or in case you have a single module project), if you like:

https://github.com/SoftSmithy/softsmithy-parent/blob/develop/pom.xml

Just make sure you override the project-specific sections such as organization, scm, issueManagement, developers, licenses etc.

Comment: I'm not sure it is true for core plugins. Upgrading a Maven version is a conscious decision. On the other hand, pinning the version for each core plugin doesn't make much sense to me because they are already set in META-INF/plexus/default-bindings.xml. Maven also seems OK with that as long as you don't try to modify the configuration. What happens if a new core plugin is introduced?